# Android Studio: Wrong username in git pull/fetch dialog

Tags: git

I am using git in the Android Studio when I am trying to pull, fetch then it is asking password for `--global`.

[image]

Comment: What’s the error? And what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You probably ran this:

```
git config credential.username --global username
```

Instead of

```
git config --global credential.username username
```

To fix it, do:

```
git config credential.username username
```

And to do what you originally intended to do:

```
git config --global credential.username username
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try entering username and password for your GitHub account or try login with Github.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1034539)

Comment: The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJYBb.png) provided in the description says `Login to Github.com` in the title, so I don't think its a bad idea to enter github credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If your remote is https you might enter username and password every time! you can check remote with this command:

```
git remote -v
```

If you see something like this: origin **https**://github.com/myusername/project.git , then it's HTTPS remote.

You can connect your remote with **ssh which is better than https**, and you don't need to enter your username/password every time.

but with ssh you will see remote like this:

```
origin  git@git.bugloos.work:myusername/project.git
```

based on your operating system it's different to do it, search how to generate ssh key and add it into the GitHub on Linux/Windows/Mac.